# Can an opened pack of dried yeast be stored for later use?

Tags: yeast

I purchased a 25 gm active dry yeast. It says to use it with 500 ml flour. However I just want to make a couple of pizza bases, 100 gm each max. So can I use 40% of it today, and use the rest later? How to store the open pack, do I need to seal it and pack?

Comment: Beside the storage matter, there is some confusion with your numbers. 500 ml of flour are 265 g, not 500 g. Also using 25 g dry yeast with 265 g flour is really a lot (it's also too much if the package says 500 g, not 500 ml). Per 100 g of flour, you should use between 0.5 g and 2.5 g of *dry* yeast, the lower limit is for slower rises and plainer doughs, the upper limit is for quick rises and highly enriched doughs (lots of fat and sugar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can store an opened pack of dried yeast without a problem. Seal the pack as well as you can (plastic clips for just that purpose are very common, or you can just use an office 'bulldog' clip), and put it in the fridge.

Comment: Anecdotal: I have had problems with leftover dry yeast where I didn't take any storage precations, i.e. just folded the top and left it in the cupboard. The expiration date was kind of close too.

Comment: Yup. You need to seal it and keep it cold.

Comment: a popular alternative to bulldog clips are barbie purse clips

Answer (score 1):

I keep my active dry yeast in freezer (aprox -10C) to avoid humidity and fungus as freezers have higher dehydration than fridge (1-7C). 
The same is not valid for the liquid yeast. Freezer will kill the bacteria.

Comment: Yeast are not bacteria, they are fungi.

Comment: Thanks Dan for correction. It's important to know that all microorganisms are not bacteria.